# How can I fix this function to recursively search an object for all instances of a key?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

I'm trying to traverse an object to find all instances of a key, and get any value associated with the key. (The object may have a key multiple times at different depths)

I find the value I want just fine, however when I try to step backwards from a recursive "TraverseQuestData" (after finding a value), I get stuck in an infinite loop.

I've been looking a this for hours now and can't seem to find where the issue is. Would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

```
//traverse table for search_key. add anything to returning data that is a value associated with the search key
function TraverseQuestData(quests, search_key, token_cap, token_partial){
    level_data = []
    for(var key of Object.keys(quests)){
        var value = quests[key]

        if(typeof(value) == "object"){

            var extra_strings = _.cloneDeep(TraverseQuestData(value, search_key, token_cap, token_partial + key + '_'))
            for(i=0; i < extra_strings.length; i++){
                level_data.push(extra_strings[i]); 
            }
        } else if(key == search_key){
            level_data.push({
                token: (token_partial + token_cap),
                value: value
            });
        }
    }
    return level_data;
}
```

Comment: please add an object, the call of the function and the wanted result.

Comment: Does `quests` have cycles?

Comment: ....As always, I managed to solve the problem after asking for help.. (seems to be a common occurence for me).

I was in the process of getting the information for your requests and between cleaning the code and logging the related object, I realized that i hadn't put a 'var' or 'let' infront of  "level_data = []". Resulting in it being a global and growing exponentially.

It turns out this wasn't an infinite loop just an exponentially larger and larger one to the point where it became indistinguishable from one.

Thankyou so much for the help!

How should I close this question?

Comment: please close the question, or answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a silly mistake.

level_data was not defined with var or let resulting in it sitting within the global scope. Properly scoping the variable fixed this!

This wasn't an infinite loop but due to the size of the objects was indistinguishable from one (the program crashed because there were too many steps)